# My solution to Project Euler #8 not working anymore

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, for-loop, numbers

I solved a problem online where I found the Largest product of any 5 consecutive numbers In a 1000-digit number:

```
        var bignumber = "7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450";
    var bigarray = bignumber.split("");
    var prod = [];
    var buy = 1;
    var z = 4;
    for (var i = 0; i < bigarray.length; i+=z) {
      mult = bigarray[i];
      for (var x = 1; x <= z; x++) {
        mult *= bigarray[i+x];
      }
      prod.push(mult);
    }
    prod.sort(function(a, b){return b-a});
    document.write(prod[0]);
```

where z can be the number of the consecutive digits I want minus 1, and the solution was 40824 which is correct I think [solution](http://ventusmoso.com/projecteuler/solutions-1-10/project-euler-solution-to-problem-8-written-in-perl-python-ruby-and-javascript/)

Later I found that this problem belonged to Project Euler [here](https://projecteuler.net/problem=8), but instead It's 13 consecutive digits, so when I tried to change z = 12, it gave me an incorrect solution, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake is in line `for (var i = 0; i < bigarray.length; i+=z) {`:

1. Change the loop condition to `i < bigarray.length - z`. Reason: Since the inner for loop advances up to z indices, the outer loop has to guarantee that there are at least z elements remining from index `i`.
2. Change the loop increment to `i+=1`. Reason: Consider finding the largest product of two consecutive digits in input `"1221"`. `1*2 = 2` and `2*1 = 2` is what your algorithm computes. The solution however is `2*2 = 4` which can only be found when considering every input digit as a possible starting point.

Once you made these changes, you could start optimizing your algorithm. For example, you can kind of re-use the `mult` value from the previous iteration.

Answer (score 0):

You may do as follows;

```js
function getMaxProductConseq(s,n){
  return Math.max(...s.split("")
                      .map((_,i,a) => a.slice(i,i+n))
                      .slice(0,s.length-n+1)
                      .map(sa => sa.reduce((p,c) => +p * +c)));
}

var bignumber = "7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450";
console.log(getMaxProductConseq(bignumber,13));
```

Comment: thanks for the effort but yours calculate the sum not the product + I don't want a new solution I want to know what's wrong with my code

Comment: @Ahmed Muhammad Oh just a slight misinterpretation. Thanks for the heads up. Now it should be fine. Sorry i am no good in debugging. Much faster to get it done from scratch. Please take it just as an idea for your future reference.